# Angular's @Input not working, whereas metadata input array is

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that is calling a child component and passing it an object. Here's how the code looks:

Parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

import { ImagesService } from '../../shared/services/images.service'
import { Image } from '../../shared/models/image.model'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './gallery.template.html'
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  images: Image[] = []

  constructor(private imagesService: ImagesService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.images = await this.imagesService.getList()
  }
}
```

Its template:

```
<sh-image *ngFor="let image of images"
          [image]="image"></sh-image>
```

That's the child component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { Image } from '../../shared/models/image.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'sh-image',
  templateUrl: './image.template.html',
  inputs: [
    'image'
  ]
})
export class ImageComponent {
  // @Input() image: Image
}
```

For some reason when I use the `@Input() image: Image` line, I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: image_model_1 is not defined`. However, everything works just fine, if I use the metadata bindings.

While it works, I would really like to use the `@Input` decorator, or at least find out why it's not working. Any help is appreciated :) Thank you

UPD: I'm posting the `Image` interface code just in case, however, it didn't raise any suspicion because it's referenced just fine in the parent component:

```
export interface Image {
  id: string,
  path: string,
  title: string
}
```

UPD2: Posting the app module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module'

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { GalleryComponent } from './components/gallery/gallery.component'

import { ImagesService } from './shared/services/images.service'
import { ImageComponent } from './components/image/image.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GalleryComponent,
    ImageComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    Title,
    ImagesService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Have you checked from which line the error is coming?

Comment: Looks like the problem is not with your inputs but your `Image` interface. Where are these components declared?

Comment: @SherKhan yes, it says the error comes from the `@Input() image: Image` line

Comment: @echonax the `Image` interface didn't make me suspicious because it works well in the parent component. I will add its code to the question

Comment: @SkaN the error says `image_model_1 is not defined` so most probably the child component can't get the reference imo. Are the parent and the child components in the the same directory level? Is the path correct? And can you add the `@NgModule` which these components are declared in?

Comment: @echonax you seem to be correct, I changed the type to `any` and it worked. The paths are totally correct, the IDE would let me know, if it was otherwise. I will post the module in a moment

Comment: @echonax the `image` was an actual interface. I changed it to a class and it works now... Not sure what difference did it make

Comment: @SkaN that's definitely weird.

Comment: Does (,) comma in your interface matter? Maybe syntax issue? Use semi-colon instead.